# Is the use of dynamic files a correct pattern for server deployment?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Let's say I have a grunt task that starts an external server. Does it makes sense using dynamic files to map the files that should be deployed into the server when it runs? (http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically)

For instance, I want to copy a file inside a directory named "test/files/loaded.txt" into the started server's root "/loaded.txt" instead of "/test/files/loaded.txt".

I would be using `grunt.file.copy` in this case for each mapped file.

Is the pattern below the correct use for this? It seems incorrect because it doesn't specify a dest property.

```
files: [{
  expand: true,
  cwd: "test/files/",
  src: [ "loaded.txt" ]
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.

Grunt will normalize the "dest" and "src" paths of the files.

"src" will be the original "test/files/loaded.txt", and "dest" will be the rest of the path without the "cwd" context.

You can then read the file and copy to the "dest" relative to the server deployment directory. The same works if you specify the "src" and "dest" paths without dynamic files pattern:

```
this.files.forEach(function( file ) {
    var deploymentDirectory = ...
    grunt.file.copy( file.src, deploymentDirectory + file.dest );
});
```